# Is there any sense to repurpose old hdds to maximise lifetime?

Tags: hard-drive

I have some 1TB SATA drives that are used for light online data (non-boot) but they are getting old. I though that by repurposing them to be archive drives, they might last longer.

Any ideas, or studies done on how workload affects lifetime?

Comment: If they're powered up, they'll age and die

Answer (score 2):

For rotating hard disks (not SSDs), Google did studies on this a long time ago (2007).
[Their report is available here](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/archive/disk_failures.pdf).

Nothing makes a drive "last longer" -- all mechanical things eventually wear out (and even solid state stuff has a finite lifetime: SSDs have a maximum number of write cycles before they fail).  What you should really be concerned with in terms of reusing drives are two major questions.

1. Can I get any value out of this fully amortized item that I would otherwise throw in the garbage?
2. What is the chance of the item failing, and is that risk acceptable to me?

---

Note that even taking the drives offline (powered down in a closet) doesn't guarantee longevity - you may find that they won't spin up in a couple of years (a risk that increases if the drives aren't kept in a climate-controlled environment).